# Issue with Jquery and Background Position

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I currently have my website with some simple JQuery animation but it doesnt work in anything but Safari and I dont know where im going wrong:

http://www.mousehouse.org.uk/index.php

```
// Header Animations
$('nav ul li #Global_Logo').animate({'background-position-y': '0px'}, 150)
.hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'background-position-y': '-107px'}, 150);
}, function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'background-position-y': '0px'}, 150);
});
```

And this one:

```
// Work Links Animations
$('#Global_Work li a').stop().animate({backgroundPositionY: "0px", backgroundPositionX: "0px"}, 0)
.hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPositionY: "-300px", backgroundPositionX: "0px"}, 150);
}, function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPositionY: "0px", backgroundPositionX: "0px"}, 150);
});
```

Comment: your animations appear to work for me in Chrome 24.0.1312.56

Comment: the first animation (`#Global_Logo`) works in FireFox. The second doesn't. Maybe you should use 'background-position-y' on both...

Comment: are you sure? I tried on both Mac and Windows in Firefox, IE9/10 and Chrome and it doesn't work?? The logo is meant to move but currently the logo doesnt do anything and the Work Images just revert to the standard CSS backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with `backgrgroundPositionY` (and `X`) in FireFox and Opera. A common workaround is the `step` method of `animate`: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

You can animate some hidden css-property like `border-spacing` and take this as an stepper for your `step` method:

```
$('#Global_Work li a').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().css({'border-spacing': 0}).animate({
        'border-spacing': -300
    }, {
        step: function(now, fx){
            $(this).css("background-position", "0px "+now+"px");
        },
        duration: 300
    });
}, function(){
    $(this).stop().css({'border-spacing': 0}).animate({
        'border-spacing': 300
    }, {
        step: function(now, fx){
            $(this).css("background-position", "0px "+(now-300)+"px");
        },
        duration: 300
    });
});
```

This worked in my FireBug console, so I hope it works for you!

Comment: this doesn't seem to work throughout all browsers, now safari doesn't align

Comment: I set up an http://jsfiddle.net/VzkuY/ and it works on safari+FireFox+Opera on mac for me...

Comment: Sorry that was my error in understanding the code. Thank you so much!